# Building an AES50 stage snake

Tags: audio

Recently I had the opportunity to see how AES50 works in action with the Behringer X32 and two S16 digital snakes connected together with a Cat6 cable. I did a ton of research on AES50 and wasn't able to come up with anything on how it converts/sends audio signals over a cat6 cable. I'm interested in designing and building my own snakes using AES50 or anything else such as CobraNet for a reasonable price.

Comment: Do be clear, you know that you can use regular CAT5e/6 cabling, and your question is about how to mad the ADC gear on the ends?  This is quite the endeavor.

Comment: http://www.aes-media.org/sections/uk/Conf2011/Presentation_PDFs/07%20-%20Al%20Walker%20-%20Applications%20in%20Live%20Convert%20Sound.pdf  Fun stuff starts on page 17